# Directx11 - CreateTexture3D OUT_OF_MEMORY error

Tags: c++, directx, 3d, directx-11

I am creating a 3d texture in while loop just for experiment .Although i didn't forget to release it at the end ,it causing  OUT_OF_MEMORY error after some loops around 300.
my code is :

```
int cntr = 0;
while(1)
{
    ID3D11Texture3D* pTex3D = NULL;
    D3D11_TEXTURE3D_DESC desc;
      desc.Width              = 256;
      desc.Height             = 256;
      desc.Depth              = 20;
      desc.MipLevels          = 1; 
      desc.Format             = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
      desc.Usage              = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT ; 
      desc.BindFlags          = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS ;
      desc.CPUAccessFlags     = 0;  
      desc.MiscFlags          = 0;
    HRESULT hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateTexture3D(&desc, NULL, &pTex3D);
    SAFE_RELEASE( pTex3D );

    Sleep(10);

    if( hr != S_OK )
        printf("");

    cntr++;
}
```

please help me here. thanks

Comment: What is the exact error code? Also, check the return value from Release().

Comment: Resource releases are deferred in Direct3D11. If you're going to use the debug layer to report the live objects you'll see there's reference counting (the value returned from Release() and there's also internal references. If the driver doesn't have a chance to process stuff the pointers aren't released. And I think it processes stuff when the command buffer is full, unfortunately in your case you don't emit commands, so I assume they never get deallocated, try using DXGISwapChain->Present() or Context->Flush() after Release() if it's just a test.